# perl database data transfer, csv, tsv

Tags: database, perl, csv

am writting little script in perl for a client of mine, which will extract certain data from database and sends an email with this data to client via attachment. Script itself is not an issue, the problem is the file. I thought that standard .csv file will be fine and script is doing what its supposed to do with it without any issues, but clients further software that is processing data needs .tsv file without any delimiters like double quotes. Trouble is that database data contains special characters that they need, like text with new lines and double quotes in them. Once script runs it creates .tsv but special characters mess it up so they need to be escaped somehow, unfortunately i cannot use double quotes for this like in .csv file. Is there any better solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV) configured to use tabs as delimiters:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings qw(all);
use Text::CSV;

my $tsv = Text::CSV->new({
    #quote_char      => undef,
    #escape_char     => undef,
    sep_char        => "\t",
    eol             => "\n",
    quote_space     => 0,
    quote_null      => 0,
});

my @line = ("column1\t", 12345, scalar localtime);
$tsv->print(\*STDOUT, \@line);
```

Comment: thanks for response, last time I ve tried Text::CSV_XS didn't work correctly, but Ill try Text::CSV will see what happens

Comment: @Lukas it didn't worked at all or it produced results different from the expected? There are several ways of escaping characters for TSV/CSV output. Which database are you importing the data into?

Comment: it worked but results were not correct each text cell that contained new line \n messed up lines below. According to client its microsoft access but as far as i know they should be able to accept csv files as well, anyway they need to get tsv :/ thats why the problem